# Jquery or Javascript - Find the number of occurrences in an array;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me regarding the following issue:

If I have the following array:

```
sports = new Array('rugby','tennis','football','snooker','cricket','football');
```

How can I find the number of occurrences of 'football' within the array and return the index's - in this case 2 & 5;

I know I could do this with a simple for/next loop but on the end project the array will be a lot bigger and pondered if there is another way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to check every element, hence you have to use some form of a loop. What's the problem with that? o.O

Comment: [jquery] is for DOM manipulation - anything you use here will(*) be vanilla javascript.   (*) jquery does have some array manipulation methods, mostly they were available before the js equivalents.

Comment: You might be looking for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - but it won't return the indexes.

Comment: Lots of options in the closed question (mostly with loops and creating new arrays) - didn't see this solution: `sports.map((e, i) => e === "football" ? i : 0).filter(e => e != 0);` (nor this specific scenario (return the indexes)

Comment: Thanks, the above is perfect.